# Converting per-directory .htaccess (Apache) to Nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

My site was previously on an Apache server. It's a custom PHP site which has `.htaccess` on almost every folder. I have managed to get part of the `.htaccess` on the main directory to work on Nginx, but I was unable to do the same with the per-directory `.htaccess` directives.

Here are some of the `.htaccess` files:

Main `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^search(.+)/$ search.php?search=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search(.+)/page/(.+)/$ search.php?search=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^nonton/(.+)/$ download.php?download=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^nonton/(.+)/(.+)/$ download.php?download=$1&size=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^get/(.+)/$ get_dl.php?dl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)-live-streaming/$ tv.php?tv=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^thumb/(.+)$ data/thumb.php?i=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
Options -Indexes
```

URL by country:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /country/

RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?country=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/page/(.+)/$ index.php?country=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

URL by genre:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /genre/

    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?genre=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/page/(.+)/$ index.php?genre=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Tag URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tag/

RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/page/(.+)/$ index.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Page URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /title/


RewriteRule ^page/(.+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I've tried the online `.htaccess` to Nginx converter but it seems to fail. Can someone please help me to convert this `.htaccess` to Nginx?

Comment: "URL by country:" - By this do you mean the `.htaccess` file that follows is in the `/country` subdirectory, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose the main problem here is not about converting the rules but understanding where you should use them. Per-directory `.htaccess` [context](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) is Apache HTTPD specific feature and Nginx doesn't support this kind of behavior.

The Nginx equivalent is [`location`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) directive in your `nginx.conf`, e.g.

```
http {
    . . .
    server {
        . . .

        location /country/ {
            rewrite ^/country/(.+)/$ /country/index.php?country=$1 break;
            rewrite ^/country/(.+)/page/(.+)/$ /country/index.php?country=$1&page=$2 break;
        }

        location /genre/ {
            rewrite ^/genre/(.+)/$ /genre/index.php?genre=$1 break;
            rewrite ^/genre/(.+)/page/(.+)/$ /genre/index.php?genre=$1&page=$2 break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, you can use the `rewrite` rules from any [conversion tool](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) you have found, but you could also learn how to convert them by yourself, since the syntax is *extremely* similar:

- Apache's [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directive: `RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]`
- Nginx's [`rewrite`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) directive: `rewrite regex replacement [flag];`

*Replacements* are identical to the *substitutions*. The regular expression (pattern) format is same. But:

- In Nginx you have to include the leading `/` to the beginning (also `^/`, `/country/` etc.).
- *Replacements* are also root-relative, so you must must include the leading `/country/` etc.
- You need `;` in the end of every rule line.

The *flags* have these equivalents:

- `[L]` -> `last` inside `server {}` and `break` inside `location {}`.

  This part is actually crucial as most converters can't understand the contextual difference!

  > But if these directives are put inside a `location`, the `last` 
  >   flag should be replaced by `break`, or otherwise nginx will
  >   make 10 cycles and return the 500 error.
- `[R=302]` -> `redirect`
- `[R=301]` -> `permanent`

Apache's rewrite [conditions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com` can be replaced in Nginx with [`if` directives](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if): `if ($http_host ~ "^example.com") { }`, e.g.

```
        location / {
            if ($http_host ~ "^example.com"){
                rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 redirect;
            }
            rewrite ^/(.+)-live-streaming/$ /tv.php?tv=$1 break;
        }
```

The rest you can learn by reading the linked manuals and using the conversion tool for educational purposes. (I earlier linked to [apache2nginx](https://github.com/mow/apache2nginx) conversion tool that couldn't handle root-relativity and use `break` instead of `last`. Winginx's [htaccess to nginx converter](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) works better.)

Comment: Isn't the _replacement_ argument root-relative, even when used inside the `location` directive (the same for the regex/pattern)? (Or does the `location` directive influence this?) "from any conversion tool" - Well, the conversion tool you link to appears to ignore the `RewriteBase` directive and assumes the original directives are in the document root - so the resulting Nginx directives are not equivalent in this case.

Comment: Actually, both `replacement` and `regex` are root relative! I replaced the conversion tool with another that can handle `RewriteBase` and modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: I still can't understand from the original question whether there is separated `index.php`s i.e. `/genre/index.php?genre=$1` or a single `/index.php` that handles both `?country=$1` and `?genre=$1`, but I think my answer has enough information for correcting that, if misunderstood.

Comment: There would seem to be multiple `index.php` files, in each subdirectory. The _relative substitution_ and the `RewriteBase` directive ensures that it's rewritten to `/country/index.php`, etc. (Although if these additional `.htaccess` files are _inside_ the corresponding subdirectory, which seems to be implied, then there is really no need for the `RewriteBase` directive.) Bit of an aside... seems to be a lot of repetition, these directives should probably be combined - an exercise for the reader perhaps. (?)

Comment: I agree. The answer is about converting the rules instead of the quality of their contents.

Comment: Hi, yes it's multiple index.php in each directory, and still can't figure it out the correct nginx conf

Comment: Start from one set of rules and ignore the others. When you get `/country/`  working (as it is already a working example in my answer), continue to the others one by one. It is not a quick and prepared solution, but it provides leads for understanding how it actually works. I encourage you to be patient!